# svn diff summarize and awk filename with spaces issue

Tags: bash, svn

I have a bash script with a line :

```
for i in $(svn diff --summarize $REPO$OLD $REPO$NEW |awk '{print $0}'); 
 do
 print $i
```

which outputs :

```
A
https://domainname.com/projectxyz/uploads/Screen
shot
2012-05-08
at
1.57.50
PM.png
```

What I need is string in single line sth like this :

```
"Ahttps://domainname.com/projectxyz/uploads/Screen shot 2012-05-08 at 1.57.50 PM.png"
```

NOTE: **using MAC OS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around your subshell like so:

```
for i in "$(svn diff --summarize $REPO$OLD $REPO$NEW |awk '{print $0}')"
do
    echo $i
done
```

EDIT:

Can you try this method:

```
svn diff --summarize $REPOS@OLDREV $REPOS@NEWREV |
    while read line
    do
        echo $line
    done
```

Comment: I would suggest the same thing :)

Comment: Second method also works for me,thanks , check my owner answer also plz. It IFS variable in case of for loop . So your answer is more elegant than mine as its useless to tokenize twice without using each tokens when we needed a line instead. thank again

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
for i in $(svn diff --summarize $REPO$OLD $REPO$NEW |awk '{print }'); 
 do
 print $i
```

to print the whole line.

Comment: that not solved the issue: `line:https://domainxyz/branches/Contacts/src/attachments/help/uploads/Screen
line:shot
line:2012-05-08
line:at
line:1.57.50`
line:PM.png

Answer (score 0):

After doing some R&D again  I found that its not  **awk** tool but the **for** loop fault, which by default tokenises  the string based on the **IFS** variable value , which defaults to space. Even if awk returns the whole string for loop will split that depending on the **IFS**. So the working solution in my case on Mac OS is :

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(svn diff --summarize $REPO$OLD $REPO$NEW |awk '{print $0}'); 
 do
 print $i
```

I still do not know why its working under linux but not on MAC OS without setting **IFS**